# Using Map to get an object list from 2 different object lists

Tags: java

I have 2 List:

```
List<Employee> employees = List.of(
                new Employee(1, "Bob", 3),
                new Employee(2, "Nick", 1),
                new Employee(3, "Tim", 2)
        );

List<Company> companies = List.of(
                new Company(1, "Facebook"),
                new Company(2, "Google"),
                new Company(3, "Tesla")
        );
```

With 3 class:

```
class Employee {
        private Integer id;
        private String name;
        private Integer companyId;
}

class Company {
        private Integer id;
        private String name;
}

class EmployeeCompany {
        private Integer employeeId;
        private String employeeName;
        private Integer companyId;
        private String companyName;
}
```

And i have class EmployeeCompany with information of both employee and corresponding company.

I have to use Map to get a EmployeeCompany List from employees and companies:

```
[
   {
       employeeId: 1,
       employeeName: "Bob",
       companyId: 3,
       companyName: "Tesla"
   },
   {
       employeeId: 2,
       employeeName: "Nick",
       companyId: 1,
       companyName: "Facebook"
   },
   {
       employeeId: 3,
       employeeName: "Tim",
       companyId: 2,
       companyName: "Google"
   }
]
```

I have to use Map not map of Stream

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Please see: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts. It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

> I have to use Map

You don't need one.

Create a constructor / method accepting both to create a new object

```
class EmployeeCompany { 
    public EmployeeCompany(Employee e, Company c) {
        this.employeeId = e.getId();
        // TODO
    } 
}
```

Create at least one method for cross referencing the lists

```
private static Optional<Company> findCompany(int id, List<Company> companies) {
    return companies.stream().filter(c -> c.getId() == id).findFirst();
}
```

Iterate one list, and join against the other

```
List<EmployeeCompany> ec = employees.stream().map(e -> {
    Company c = findCompany(companies, e.getCompanyId()).get();
    return new EmployeeCompany(e, c);
}).collect(toList());
```

Starting with a `Map<Integer, String> companies` would be simpler

Answer (score 0):

By simply putting in the appropriate constructors and setters of your classes you can  do it as follows:

- Iterate thru the list of employees
- Then iterate thru the list of companies.
- when you find the company id that matches the current employee's company you simply create a new `EmployeeCompany` instance and place it in the list.
- if no match is found, the employee entry is ignored.

```
List<EmployeeCompany> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (Employee emp : employees) {
    for(Company com : companies) {
        if (com.getId() == emp.getCompanyId()) {
            result.add(new EmployeeCompany(emp.getId(),emp.getName(), com.getId(),
                    com.getName()));
        
            break;
        }
    }
    // if this is reached, then no match was found.  Additional
    // code could be placed here to print an informatory message.
}

for(EmployeeCompany ec : result) {
    System.out.println(ec);
}
```

prints

```
{EmployeeId=1, EmployeeName=Bob, CompanyId=3, CompanyName=Tesla}
{EmployeeId=2, EmployeeName=Nick, CompanyId=1, CompanyName=Facebook}
{EmployeeId=3, EmployeeName=Tim, CompanyId=2, CompanyName=Google}
```

Here is the `toString()` override I used for the `EmployeeCompany` class. It can be altered as required.

```
public String toString() {
    return String.format("{EmployeeId=%s, EmployeeName=%s, CompanyId=%s, CompanyName=%s}",
          employeeId, employeeName, companyId, companyName);
}
```